# sendmail with attachment being encoded

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm trying to utilize the sendmail function in unix but can't seem to get the attachment to come through...my code is the follwoing:

```
export MAILTO="me@myco.com"
export SUBJECT="test mail"
export ATTACH="/home/tstattach"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
 echo "this is a test message"
 base64 $ATTACH 
) | sendmail $MAILTO
```

my email message comes through like this with no attachment:

```
this is a test message
dGVzdCBhdHRhY2htZW50
---q1w2e3r4t5--
```

how do I get the attachment to come through? it seems like its encoding it in a weird way...I've tried uuencode as well instead of base64 but then I get an error saying uuencode not found...

Answer (score 5):

OK, feeling nice today. Here's a working one (tested):

```
export MAILTO="me@myco.com"
export SUBJECT="test mail"
export ATTACH="/home/tstattach"
(
    echo "Date: $(date -R)"
    echo "To: $MAILTO"
    echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
    echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
    echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
    echo
    echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
    echo 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    echo 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'
    echo
    echo "this is a test message"
    echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
    echo 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; name=attach.txt'
    echo 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
    echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attach.txt'
    echo
    base64 <"$ATTACH"
    echo
    echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | sendmail $MAILTO
```

But please **do** do yourself a favour and read up on eMail (RFC822 and its replacement) and MIME (RFCs around 2047).